# multiple layout print on a page

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I use eagle-cad 6.0. when I print the circuit layout onto PDF, it prints one circuit per page. However, my board has a small size and 4 layout could fit a A4 page without any problem. Could anyone tell me how I can print 4 copies of the layout onta a A4 page without changing the actual dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mattyoung suggests, you want to panelize. Eagle doesn't panelize. However there is an incredible piece of software which panelizes gerber files fantastically well. It's called [gerbmerge](http://ruggedcircuits.com/gerbmerge/), and it's free. It runs on Windows and Linux (and OSX, and anything that can run unixy code).

I highly recommend it for this kind of work.

Comment: I see gerbmerge can add v-grooves, but can it add mills between the boards if you have pieces off the edge?

Comment: looking at the config file documentation it looks like this is handled by the outline layer.

Answer (score 1):

Make a panel out of your boards, and print the necessary layers from that.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the Eagle Cad. Could you explain how I can do it?

Comment: I'm not either, you'll have to look it up in the manual. Every PCB layout software has the capability.

Comment: That, of course, changes the board, not just the figure.

Comment: Does Eagle not have the ability to just make a panel? Every layout software I have ever used has had the option to make a panel from an existing board. That does not change the board at all.

Comment: http://3lectronics.com/panelizing-in-eagle-how-to-panelize-pcb-layout-in-cadsoft-eagle/